# Show a <div> when the user clicks a link with href "#"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, if-statement

The script should **check the document** every time the user clicks a link. If the `href` is **#**, the script should show a div with the ID *video*.

(I need this specific piece as a patch for an image gallery. I'm having trouble using the `title` attribute for specific content for different images in the gallery.)

Pseudo code:

```
If user clicks <a> with href="#"
Show div #video
```

Comment: No. - I mean href="#"   nothing else^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(){
    $("#video").show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a[href="#"]').click(function(){
    $("#videoDiv").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href="#"]')
```

Then do your show div!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$('a[href=#]').click(myFunction);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a[href$=#]').click(function(e){
    $("#video").show();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) - What does e.preventDefault(); do?

Comment: it will prevent the default action of an anchor element, without preventDefault or return false, the # 'hash' will be appended on the page url when you click the a element