# How to show div when click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link with class yes and I want to show a `div` with classname `(box)` when the link is clicked. I wrote the below code but it does not work and display nothing when clicked . here is my snippet :

```js
$('.yes').on('click', function(e){  e.preventDefault();  $(this).siblings('.box').toggleClass('active');})
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
.box.active {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.box.active.good {
  -webkit-animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
          animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>          
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="yes">Show Box</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box good" style="width:200px; height:200px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: May be this one can help
[Show a <div> when the user clicks a link with href “#”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284558/show-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-a-link-with-href)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use directly class selector `$('.box')`, if you've only one box.

```
$('.box').toggleClass('active');
```

If you've multiple `.box` after each ul, use `.parents()`

```
$(this).parents('ul').next().toggleClass('active');
```

```js
$('.yes').on('click', function(e){  
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $('.box').toggleClass('active');
  //$(this).parents('ul').next().toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
.box.active {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.box.active.good {
  -webkit-animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
          animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>          
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="yes">Show Box</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box good" style="width:200px; height:200px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Its not direct sibling to your anchor tag. It's sibling to "ul"**

```js
$('.yes').on('click', function(e){  e.preventDefault();  $(this).parents("ul").siblings('.box').toggleClass('active');})
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
.box.active {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.box.active.good {
  -webkit-animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
          animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>          
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="yes">Show Box</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box good" style="width:200px; height:200px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `<a href="#tab-1" class="yes">` element has no siblings. [`$(this).siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) is returning nothing.

## To fix this, you could use this alternative javascript:

```
$('.yes').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents("ul").siblings('.box').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Expand the code snippet for a demonstration:

```js
$('.yes').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents("ul").siblings('.box').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
.box.active {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.box.active.good {
  -webkit-animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
          animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>          
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="yes">Show Box</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box good" style="width:200px; height:200px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

But basically, your anchor tag and your box are not siblings, this can be shown by indentation:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tab-1" class="yes">Show Box</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box good" style="width:200px; height:200px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
```

Siblings need to be at the same level. Maybe this diagram will help you better understand what siblings are:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.yes').on('click', function(e){  
e.preventDefault(); 
$(this).parents("ul").siblings('.box').toggleClass('active');
return false;
})
```

the return false says that the link should not work but the code in the onclick will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your html the class 'yes' has no sibling.

Use this to directly show 'box' class

```
$('.yes').on('click', function(e){  
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $('.box').toggleClass('active');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are traversing in wrong way. Please make it as right like be

```js
$('.yes').on('click', function(e){  e.preventDefault();  $(this).closest('ul').next('.box').toggleClass('active');})
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
.box.active {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.box.active.good {
  -webkit-animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
          animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>          
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="yes">Show Box</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box good" style="width:200px; height:200px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.yes').on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();  $(this).parents().siblings('.box').toggleClass('active');})
```

```css
.box {
  display: none;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, opacity .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
.box.active {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.box.active.good {
  -webkit-animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
          animation: anim .3s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>          
<ul>
<li><a href="#tab-1" class="yes">Show Box</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="box good" style="width:200px; height:200px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```